# My program crashes, and I don't understand why

Tags: c

I am coding a record-keeping program in C using binary file handling. I am using Code::Blocks, with gcc to compile my C program on Windows 8.

When the program reaches to the following block, an error-message appears:

[image]

My code:

```
int dispaly(student record[], int count)
{

/*
This is what structure `student` looks like:

 int id;
    char name[200], phone[20], address[200], cclass[50];
    char sec[20], roll[50], guardian_name[200], relation[200] ;
    char p2_colg[100], slc_school[200];
    float plus2_percent, slc_percent;
    struct date dob;
    struct date enr_date;


    struct date looks like
       int day, month, year;
*/
printf("Reached"); /*Program Runs Fine upto here*/
int i = 0;
for(i=0; i<count; i++)
{
    printf("\nId: %d\tPhone: %s\nName: %s\nAddress: %s"
           "\nClass: %s\tSection: %s\nRoll: %s\nGuardian Name: %s\tRelation:%s"
           "\nPlus-Two in: %s\tPercentage:%f\nSLC School: %s\tPercentage: %f"
           "\nDate Of Birth(mm/dd/yyyy): %d/%d/%d"
           "\nEnrolled in (mm/dd/yyyy): %d/%d/%d\n\n---------------------------------------\n", record[i].id, record[i].name, record[i].address
           , record[i].cclass, record[i].sec, record[i].roll, record[i].guardian_name, record[i].relation, record[i].p2_colg
           , record[i].plus2_percent, record[i].slc_school, record[i].slc_percent, record[i].dob.month, record[i].dob.day, record[i].dob.year
           , record[i].enr_date.month, record[i].enr_date.day, record[i].enr_date.year);

}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

The program compiles without any errors or warnings.

What's going on?

Comment: I really hope your function isn't actually called `dispaly`. Also, I think "GNU GCC" is redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hard to tell exactly what crashed without looking at the exact data in your array, but you forgot "phone" in the arguments list to printf, which could certainly result in a crash inside printf.

Comment: Also, compile wtih '-Wextra`, if you aren't doing.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a terribly good reason to stack those all up into one call.  It would have been easier to spot your bug of the missing "phone" if you separated each line out into its own `printf`.  Also, you could cut down on the redundancy if you captured `record[i]` into a pointer.

Contrast with:

```
student * r = &record[i];

printf("\n");

printf("Id: %d\tPhone: %s\n", r->id, r->phone);

printf("Name: %s\n", r->name);

printf("Address: %s\n", r->address);

printf("Class: %s\tSection: %s\n", r->cclass, r->sec);

printf("Roll: %s\n", r->roll);

printf("Guardian Name: %s\tRelation:%s\n", r->guardian_name, r->relation);

printf("Plus-Two in: %s\tPercentage:%f\n", r->p2_colg, r->plus2_percent);

printf("SLC School: %s\tPercentage: %f\n", r->slc_school, r->slc_percent);

printf("Date Of Birth(mm/dd/yyyy): %d/%d/%d\n",
       r->dob.month, r->dob.day, r->dob.year);

printf("Enrolled in (mm/dd/yyyy): %d/%d/%d\n"
       r->enr_date.month, r->enr_date.day, r->enr_date.year);

printf("\n");

printf("---------------------------------------\n");
```

In a technical sense, making multiple calls to `printf` will incur *some* function call overhead.  And declaring a pointer variable for the current student in the array will incur *some* storage space.  But it is basically negligible, and of no consequence in a case like this.  Under the hood, the output is buffered anyway.